# Installed PHPUnit Via PEAR But Cannot Find PHPUnit.bat To Add To Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, pear

i installed PHPUnit via pear and cannot find the phpunit.bat file to add to the path in netneans. Where should it be? My pear dir is c:/server/xampp/php/PEAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in c:/server/xampp/php

Comment: Yeah found it, i thought it would be in the PEAR folder.